# 'Type' does not contain a definition for 'GetMethod'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, windows-store-apps

I keep getting error:

> CS1061: 'Type' does not contain a definition for 'GetMethod' and no
>   extension method 'GetMethod' accepting a first argument of type 'Type'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?).

I am trying to build for Windows Store apps!

And here is my code:

```
MethodInfo theMethod = itween.GetType().GetMethod (animation.ToString(), new Type[] {
        typeof(GameObject),
        typeof(Hashtable)
});
theMethod.Invoke(this, parameters);
```

Answer (score 4):

To use Reflection in Windows Store app, *TypeInfo* class is used instead of the *Type* class, which is used in classic .NET applications.

However, it still comes with some restrictions:

> In a Windows 8.x Store app, access to some .NET Framework types and members is restricted. For example, you cannot call .NET Framework methods that are not included in .NET for Windows 8.x Store apps, by using a MethodInfo object.

Reference: [Reflection in the .NET Framework for Windows Store Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/reflection-for-windows-store-apps)

A code snippet corresponding to yours is like:

```
using System.Reflection; //this is required for the code to compile

var methods = itween.GetType().GetTypeInfo().DeclaredMethods;
foreach (MethodInfo mi in methods)
{
    if (mi.Name == animation.ToString())
    {
        var parameterInfos = mi.GetParameters();
        if (parameterInfos.Length == 2)
        {
            if (parameterInfos[0].ParameterType == typeof(GameObject) &&
                parameterInfos[1].ParameterType == typeof(Hashtable))
            {
                mi.Invoke(this, parameters)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `GetTypeInfo` is defined as extension method, so `using System.Reflection;` is required for the compiler to recognize this method.